# PHP - get position of tag with DomDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

```
<a>
    <b id="bye">
        <name>john</name>
    </b>
    <b id="goodbye">
        <name>emma</name>
    </b>
</a>
```

Using that XML file, I want to print something like:

```
b with id:bye has position 0
b with id:goodbye has position 1
```

Comment: Define position? Relative to what? Sibling index? How are you displaying the items? Are you looping through a domnodelist?

Comment: define the number of repetitions of the B tag, and the print the position of each one. No line number and all document

Comment: Which library are you using to parse this xml?

Comment: i'm using domdocument with getElementsByTagName, createElement etc functions and then i save the xml

Comment: I've answered this below using getElementsByTagName as you mention here, with an almost identical output to your original request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dom's XPath to get what you need ( updated to output a better match to original post ).

```
<?php

$xml = '<a>
    <b id="bye">
        <name>john</name>
    </b>
    <b id="goodbye">
    <name>emma</name>
    </b>
</a>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName("b") as $domNode ) {
    print "b with id:{$domNode->attributes->getNamedItem("id")->nodeValue} has position {$domNode->getNodePath()}\n";
}
```

Should provide you with:

```
b with id:bye has position /a/b[1]
b with id:goodbye has position /a/b[2]
```

Comment: i'm getting the xml from a file

Comment: You could use loadXML(file_get_contents($yourFile)), or loadHTMLFile($yourFile)